# Call a collection once, and filter it several times firebase Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

at the moment I call my collection with a filter, but I would like to display my data in several different tables on the same page by filtering the data in the same table with a different .where().

For the moment, I only know how to filter by call, i.e. I'm going to call it and filter it.

But I would like to know if there is a way to call it once and dispatch it by filtering it instead of calling it several times and filtering it several times.

```
 function getOrders(uid) {
    fire.firestore().collection("orders")
    .where("statut", "==", "Validé")
    .orderBy('time', 'desc')
    
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      setOrders(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          orderid: doc.data().id,
          statut: doc.data().statut,
          nomproduit: doc.data().nomproduit,
          type: doc.data().type
          
        }),setLength(querySnapshot.docs.length))
        
      );
      
    });
    
  }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Once you have your array of data back from Firestore, any reason you can't use `Array.filter()` or `Array.reduce()` to return a new filtered version of your data?

Comment: I don't know how to use it

Comment: Basically there isn't enough information on what you looking to do. One thing I didn't think of last night when I commented is that you can't run `OR` queries in Firestore. If you data has 20 possible different values for `statut` and you want three of them for different views, the **only** way to do that is three queries; one query for each set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? I believe this is the type of filtering you want. You can read more about these queries [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries) and also search through helpful [GCP code snippets for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/docs/samples?p=firestore).

```js
// Create a reference to the cities collection
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');

const stateQueryRes = await citiesRef.where('state', '==', 'CA').get();
const populationQueryRes = await citiesRef.where('population', '<', 1000000).get();
const nameQueryRes = await citiesRef.where('name', '>=', 'San Francisco').get();
```